# Mysqli prepared statement issue with get_result

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have been using the traditional method of query db with out prepared statement. So decided to move to prepared statement now as below are my codes.

```
$link = new mysqli(dbHost, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDatabase);
if($link->connect_error) {
 die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($link->connect_error));
}
$stmt = $link->stmt_init();
$selectQuery1 ="Select *  From tblUser  Where tblUser.userName=? ";
$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($link, $selectQuery1);
if ( false===$stmt1 ) {

  die('stmt1 prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}
$rc1 = $stmt1->bind_param('s', $userName);
if ( false===$rc ) {
  die('rc1 bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt1->error));
}

$execute1 = $stmt1->execute();
if ( false===$execute1 ) {
   die('execute1 execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt1->error));
}
$store1=$stmt1->store_result();
if ( false===$store1 ) {
  die('store1() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt1->error));
}
$count1=$stmt1->num_rows;

$result1 = $stmt1->get_result();
if ( false===$result1 ) {
  die('result1 () failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt1->error));
}
```

The query worked well till this line $count1=$stmt1->num_rows; and the moment I put this codes $result1 = $stmt1->get_result(); my page failed and I found out that I must now change to mysql native driver etc. My biggest worry is by changing the driver it might effect all my other existing application. So what is the best mechanism to mitigate is there any other method to retrieve the result or move to PDO ? I want to be able to use this mechanism mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) to get my select results ?

Comment: Adding the native driver will not adversely effect existing code, and in some cases it may improve performance. PDO does make things easier, but if you can't switch, your options would be that `get_result()`, or `bind_result()` with variables for each column.

Comment: Yes I am a bit lost here to switch to PDO or not? What is the their different with mysqli and pdo? How to get_result with variable I dont quite get you here ?